# How to hide the next button until a certain time of day in Qualtrics survey

Tags: javascript, qualtrics

I am trying to hide the next button on a Qualtrics survey until a specific day/time (var threshold in my code). I have tried

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()
{
    var threshold = '2020-02-07T20:00:00.000Z';
    var today = new Date();
    if(threshold < today) $('NextButton').hide();
    else $('NextButton').show();

});
```

and

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function() {   
    function hideEl(element) {
        element.hide();
    }   
    var nb = $('NextButton');
    var threshold = '2020-02-07 08:12';
    var today = new Date();
    var date = today.getFullYear()+'-'+(today.getMonth()+1)+'-'+today.getDate();
    var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes();
    var dateTime = date+' '+time;
        hideEl.defer(nb);
    if(var dateTime < threshold ) nb.hide();
    else nb.show();

    });
```

and

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function() {
    function hideEl(element) {
        element.hide();
    }
    var threshold = '2020-02-07T20:00:00.000Z';
    var today = new Date();
    var nb = $('NextButton');
    hideEl.defer(nb);
 $(this.questionId).on('display', function(event) {
        if(today<threshold) nb.hide();
        else nb.show();
    });
});
```

but have not been able to get it to work. Any ideas?

Thank you!!

Comment: I guess that  `$('.NextButton')` will do it?

Comment: Does A. Meshu's comment resolve your issue?  Is it just a question of not having the correct selector to get a ref to your button element?

Comment: Thanks for the help on this. Adding the . did not do the trick :/ I am thinking it has something to do with the date formats so I am playing around with that logic now.

Answer (score 0):

If you're hoping to load the page, then leave it in place and wait for your button to show, then it won't work since your onload code only runs once. You could calculate how far away in ms your time to show the button is when the page loads, then set a timeout to run the code showing the button after that amount of ms has passed.

```js
function onLoadCb() {
  // When do you want your button to be revealed:
  const timeToShow = new Date('<whenver your date is>);
  // Convert that to milliseconds:
  const msToShow = Number(timeToShow);
  // Get the milliseconds right now:
  const now = Date.now();
  // Do math!
  const msToWait = msToShow - now;

  // Set a timeout that will wait the number of ms that we calculated:
  setTimeout(() => {
    // That amount of time has passed, show the button!
    $('.NextButton').show();
  }, msToWait);
}
```

Comment: If you right this question should be close due typo (OP didn't add dot on selector  class name) don't you think?

Comment: It depends on the OP's intent... if they just aren't getting the button selector right, then yes.  If they're trying to figure out how to do asynchronous, time-based behavior on their project and the selector isn't the issue, then I think that this is a reasonable solution :D

Comment: Without seeing HTML or use Qualtrics survey it seems that all his trying failed due to the selector. If he would console.log it he would see the null or even an error...